WindowsからLinux側のSamba共有フォルダへPythonでファイルを転送したい
クライアントPC: Windows 10 (Python 3.10) ※ 他linuxマシン有り
サーバーPC: MX Linux 21 (Python 3.9,共有フォルダ有り)　SambaやsmbClientを利用しています。
Linux側の共有は開通が確認しています。手動でも問題なくファイル転送が出来ています
(Linuxから別のLinuxへのファイル転送はsmbClientで問題なくできます)
Windowsから(共有側の)Linuxへのファイル転送(コピー)はできるのですが、
その直後の処理がフリーズして先の処理が止まってしまいます。
# motoパスの内容 C:/text/test.csv

moto = 'C:/text'
saki = '\\192.168.1.8/share/test/'

if os.path.exists(saki) == True:

    print('下記のファイルコピーは出来ます')

    new_path = shutil.copytree(moto,saki,dirs_exist_ok=True)

    print('ここから先が進みません')

根本的にPythonで普通のコピーではダメなのでしょうか？
LinuxのsmbClientのような特殊な記述方法がWindows側にも必要なのでしょうか？
Windowsマシン側にある共有フォルダには普通のPythonコードで問題なく作動しました。
Linux側にある共有フォルダにWindows側から新規でフォルダを作成することもできました。

参考: 英語版での類似質問と回答 Copy files to network path or drive using python on OSX

この記事が参考になるかも。Python - transfer files in the same network using shutil あとこの記事の質問や回答にあるように各パス(特にsaki)の先頭のシングルクォテーションの前にrを付けてr'\\192.168.1.8/share/test/'にしてみてはどうでしょう？

ご連絡ありがとうございます。r'\192.168.1.8/share/test/'を試して見ましたが、やはり変化がありませんでした。ネットで調べていたらparamiko SFTPの記述があり。調べてみたいと思います
